# Can I change chat id?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the appengine. I'm going to use an app named Square for this example.

We have the domain www.square.com.

We cannot get square.appspot.com

We do have squares.appspot.com.

For moving the app over the www.square.com. We did this. Great! Very exciting.

But we also built a chat bot. We now need people to friend 'squares'. What we want is for people to friend 'square'.

So two questions please: Is there a way to get Square.appengine.com. From my research... I assume someone took it and it's now gone (remember 'square' just an example here).

Knowing #1... is there a way to change the chat bot 'name'? From Squares.appspot.com --> Square.appspot.com?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Why do you "now need people to friend 'squares'."? How is this needed for chat?

Comment: If you've built the chat bot, why can't you just change it's name yourself? If you are asking how can you use square.appspot.com the answer is you can't, it's too late, any reference you make to that in your application will always resolve to the site you don't control.

Answer (score 0):

It's a chat bot, for us to send a message to an individual they have to have it as a friend. In their friends list they see: squares.appspot.com. This isn't our domain or our name. We need it to say square.appspot.com. Preferably we could change the name...

which leads to the second question... how do we change the name that people see.

"If you've built the chat bot, why can't you jsut change it's name yourself?"

Am I missing something this simple? How?